# Python syntax returning only part of the if/elif statement in Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

Using ArcGIS 10.7 desktop.

I want to reclassify a land use field using Field Calculator. Grasslands are conditionally reclassified using a 'veg_type' field (Avena, or Bromus) and a CWHR land use field (grassland values = Annual Grassland, AGS, Perennial Grassland). All other values in the CWHR field should stay the same.

When I run the Python Parser syntax the Grassland_Reclass field returns "Avena Grassland" (gridcode = 1) for the assigned land use values, but also for grasslands categorized as "Bromus' (gridcode = 0). The default CWHR values are added, but the elif condition (gridcode = 0) is not returned. I've also tried with the veg_type field but I get the same result.

```
def Reclass(gridcode, CWHR_TYPE):
  if gridcode == 1 and CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland":
    return "Avena Grassland"
  elif gridcode == 0 and CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland":
    return "Bromus Grassland"  
  else:
    return CWHR_TYPE
```

Expression: Grassland_Reclass =

```
Reclass(!gridcode!, !CWHR_TYPE!)
```

[image]

Comment: Just an observation, the only effective value that defines the outcome is `gridcode`, given the rest to the right hand side is the same. Also, pyhon has `in` operator and it is great replacement for multiple `or`s and easier to read, e.g., `CWHR_TYPE in ("Annual Grassland", "AGS", "Perennial Grassland")`

Comment: If you have a table of data, and you want to select all rows having some properties (e.g. `CWHR_TYPE` is "`Annual Grassland`") the correct language to use is `SQL`. Do not use python. Use `SQL`. `SQL` is quite literally, designed to do nothing but manage tables of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logical operator precedence and order of operators is causing your issue. Try grouping your `or`s in parentheses:

e.g.

Wrong:

```
def Reclass(gridcode, CWHR_TYPE):
  if gridcode == 1 and CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland":
    return "Avena Grassland"
  elif gridcode == 0 and CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland":
    return "Bromus Grassland"
  else:
    return CWHR_TYPE

print(Reclass(0,"Annual Grassland"))
print(Reclass(1,"Annual Grassland"))
print(Reclass(0,"Perennial Grassland"))
print(Reclass(1,"Perennial Grassland"))
```

Output:

```
Bromus Grassland
Avena Grassland
Avena Grassland
Avena Grassland
```

Right:

```
def Reclass(gridcode, CWHR_TYPE):
    if gridcode == 1 and (CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland"):
        return "Avena Grassland"
    elif gridcode == 0 and (
            CWHR_TYPE == "Annual Grassland" or CWHR_TYPE == "AGS" or CWHR_TYPE == "Perennial Grassland"):
        return "Bromus Grassland"
    else:
        return CWHR_TYPE


print(Reclass(0, "Annual Grassland"))
print(Reclass(1, "Annual Grassland"))
print(Reclass(0, "Perennial Grassland"))
print(Reclass(1, "Perennial Grassland"))
```

Output:

```
Bromus Grassland
Avena Grassland
Bromus Grassland
Avena Grassland
```

Even better, use the `in` operator (thanks @fatih_dur):

Right:

```
def Reclass(gridcode, CWHR_TYPE):
    if gridcode == 1 and CWHR_TYPE in ("Annual Grassland", "AGS", "Perennial Grassland"):
        return "Avena Grassland"
    elif gridcode == 0 and CWHR_TYPE in ("Annual Grassland", "AGS", "Perennial Grassland"):
        return "Bromus Grassland"
    else:
        return CWHR_TYPE
```

Comment: Placing the parentheses around the CWHR values made the difference - thank you! (The binary grid code covers all CWHR land use features, not just the grasslands, which is why I needed to include the grassland classes to sort out.)

Comment: Left to right evaluation isn't relevant here. The problem is due to the precedence of `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is due to the fact that `and` takes precedence over `or`. `a and b or c` is the same as `(a and b) or c` and not `a and (b or c)`, as you assumed.

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/370289), you can use parentheses to change the precedence (because parentheses have a higher precedence than either of `and` and `or`), or even better, use `in`. You can also turn your checks around, like this:

```
def Reclass(gridcode, CWHR_TYPE):
    if CWHR_TYPE not in ("Annual Grassland", "AGS", "Perennial Grassland") or gridcode not in (0, 1):
        return CWHR_TYPE
    return "Avena Grassland" if gridcode == 0 else "Bromus Grassland"
```